# jQuery.fn this is window and causing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mobile

I am trying to make a better mobile aproach to dblclick in jQuery, but i keep on getting an error syaing `this.each is not a function`. Also, this is the global window object instead of

`jQuery.fn.dblclick = (callback) => {
        var touchtime;
        console.log({this:this});

```
    return this.each(()=>{
        $(this).on("click", function (e) {
            if (touchtime == 0) {
                touchtime = new Date().getTime();
            } else {
                if (((new Date().getTime()) - touchtime) < 800) {
                    callback(e);
                    touchtime = 0;
                } else {
                    touchtime = new Date().getTime();
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
// a few lines later...
$('button').dblclick((e)=>{...})`
```

Here is a jsfiddle: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/erkus_circus/rxno7Lvf/8/)

Comment: EDIT:  Also, this is the global window object instead of the jquery object i am trying to access.

Comment: Could you use jsfiddle and provide a working block generating the error.